# padding list of tensors with varied size

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Python list of 1-D tensors with different sizes. For example,

```py
[ tf.constant([1]), tf.constant([2,3]), tf.zeros([4,4,4]) ]
```

is there a way to pad the tensors so they have the same size, like the following,

```py
[ tf.contant([1,0,0]), tf.constant([2,3,0]), tf.constant(4,4,4) ]
```

then I can use `tf.stack` to turn them back into one tensor. These tensors are in the middle of a computation graph: they are NOT from the input.

Comment: You meant pad them to the same rank (or dimension)? If that's the case, you could try `tf.expand_dims` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims)

Comment: no, I am looking for expanding the dimensions, I am looking for padding the list of list so that they have the same size.

Comment: If that is the case, you should use `tf.expand_dims` to get the same rank. Then you could use `tf.pad` to expand the number of elements in each dimension.